# コンタクトフォームについて "入力したアドレスに送信メールが来ない。"

Tags: php, xampp

こんにちは！ヒロと申します。早速質問があります。

入力したメールアドレスに送信したメールが来ません。参考書をそのまま写したので、どこが間違っているのかわかりません。タグがいっぱいですがよろしくお願い致します。
codeigniterをxampp上に設定しました。
http://localhost/develop2/index.php/form/
ながながすいません。

-------/controllers/form.php/--------

```
<?php
class Form extends CI_Controller{

    function Form()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

        $this->load->library('session');

        $this->output->set_header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="">','</div>');

//      $fields['name'] = '名前';
//      $fields['email'] = 'メールアドレス';
//      $fields['comment'] = 'コメント';
//      $this->form_validation->set_rules($fields);
//      $rules['name'] = "trim|request|max_length[20]";
//      $rules['email'] = "trim|request|valid_email";
//      $rules['comment'] = "required|max_length[200]";
//      $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);
        //$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'ユーザ名', 'trim|required|max_length[5]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'メールアドレス', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('comment', 'コメント', 'required|max_length[200]');

$this->form_validation->set_message('required', '%sは、必須項目です');
$this->form_validation->set_message('max_length', '%sは、%s文字以内で入力してください');
$this->form_validation->set_message('valid_email', '正しいメールアドレスを指定してください');

    }
    function index()
    {
        $this->ticket = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), TRUE));
        $this->session->set_userdata('ticket', $this->ticket);

        $this->form_validation->run();

        $this->load->view('form');
    }
    function confirm()
    {
        $this->ticket = $this->session->userdata('ticket');
        if (! $this->input->post('ticket')
        || $this->input->post('ticket') !== $this->ticket )
        {
            echo 'クッキーを有効にしてください。クッキーが有効な場合は、不正な操作が行われました。';
            exit;
        }

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
        {
            $this->load->view('form_confirm');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('form');
        }
    }
    function send()
    {
        $this->ticket = $this->session->userdata('ticket');
        if (! $this->input->post('ticket')
                || $this->input->post('ticket') !== $this->ticket )
        {
            echo 'クッキーを有効にしてください。クッキーが有効な場合は、不正な操作が行われました。';
            exit;
        }
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
        {
            $mail['from_name'] = $this->validation->name;
            $mail['from'] = $this->validation->email;
            $mail['to'] = 'hironori.inoue@yahoo.com';
            $mail['subject'] = 'ｺﾝﾀｸﾄﾌｫｰﾑ';
            $mail['body'] = $this->validation->comment;

            if($this->_sendmail($mail))
            {
                $this->load->view('form_end');
                $this->session->sess_destroy();
            }
            else
            {
                echo 'ﾒｰﾙ送信ｴﾗｰ';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('form');
        }
    }
    function _sendmail($mail)
    {
        $this->load->library();
        $config['protocol'] = 'mail';

        $config['charset'] = 'ISO-2022-JP';
        $config['wordwrap'] = FALSE;
        $this->email->initialize($config);

        $from_name = $mail['from_name'];
        $from = $mail['from'];
        $to = $mail['to'];
        $subject = $mail['subject'];
        $body = $mail['body'];

        $from_name = mb_encode_mimeheader($from_name, 'ISO-2022-JP', 'UTF-8');
        $subject = mb_encode_mimeheader($subject, 'ISO-2022-JP', 'UTF-8');

        $body = mb_convert_encoding($body, 'ISO-2022-JP', 'UTF-8');

        $this->email->from($from, $from_name);
        $this->email->to($to);
        $this->email->subject($subject);
        $this->email->message($body);

        if($this->email->send())
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}
--------------------------------------------------
--------------views/form_confirm.php--------------
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url();?>css/form.css" type="text/css" />
    <title>コンタクトフォーム</title>
    <style type="text/css"></style>
</head>
<body>
 <?=$this->load->view('form_header')?>

<div id="main">
<div class="title_banner">
<img src="<?=base_url();?>images/icons/form_titile.jpg" alt="お問い合わせ" width="580" height="70" />
</div>

<div class="outer_frame">
<p class="center">お問い合わせ内容の確認</p>
<table>
<tr><th>名前</th>
<td>
    <?php /*echo form_prep('name', set_value('name'));*/ ?>
    <?php echo form_prep(set_value('name'));?>
</td>
</tr>
<tr><th>メールアドレス</th>
<td>
    <?php /*echo form_prep('name', set_value('email'));*/ ?>
    <?php echo form_prep(set_value('email')); ?>
</td>
</tr>
<tr><th>コメント</th>
<td>
    <?php /*echo form_prep('name', set_value('comment'));*/ ?>
    <?php echo form_prep(set_value('comment')); ?>
</td>
</tr>
<tr><td></td>
<td class="center">
    <?=form_open('form');?>
    <?=form_hidden('ticket', $this->ticket);?>
    <?=form_hidden('name', set_value('name'));?>
    <?=form_hidden('email', set_value('email'));?>
    <?=form_hidden('comment', set_value('comment'));?>
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="修正" />
    <?=form_close();?>

    <?=form_open('form/send');?>
    <?=form_hidden('ticket', $this->ticket);?>
    <?=form_hidden('name', set_value('name'));?>
    <?=form_hidden('email', set_value('email'));?>
    <?=form_hidden('comment', set_value('comment'));?>
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="送信" />
    <?=form_close();?>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

</div>
</div>

 <?=$this->load->view('ci_footer');?>
</body>
</html>
--------------------------------------------------
---------------view/form_end.php------------------
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url();?>css/form.css" type="text/css" />
  <style type="text/css"></style>
  <title>コンタクトフォーム(送信完了)</title>


</head>
<body>
<!-- header -->
<?=$this->load->view('form_header');?>

<!-- main -->
<div id="main">
<div class="title_banner">
<img src="<?=base_url();?>images/icons/form_title.jpg" alt="お問い合わせ" width="580" height="70" />
</div>
<div class="outer_frame">
<p class="center">送信しました</p>
<p>お問い合わせ、ありがとうございます。</p>
</div>
</div>

<!-- footer -->
<?=$this->load->view('ci_footer');?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CodeIgniterはデフォルトではPHPのメール送信機能を使うのですが、PHPはデフォルトで `sendmail` という多くのLinuxに標準で入っているプログラムを利用するようになっています。Windowsにはこれがないので、別の方法を考えないといけません。

で、XAMPPに付属するPHPの場合、「送信したメールをファイルとして保存する」という設定がなされています。XAMPPのインストール先にある `mailoutput` というフォルダに何か保存されていませんか？

もし実際に任意のアドレスに対してメールを送信したいのであれば、

- 送信元となるメールアドレスをGmailなどで一つ用意して
- `xampp\sendmail\sendmail.ini` にそのアカウント情報を設定し
- `xampp\php\php.ini` の `sendmail_path` を、コメントアウトされている `sendmail.exe` に変更する

といった作業が必要になります。

参考： [「XAMPP for Windows」の環境でsendmailの設定を行う。｜マコトのおもちゃ箱](http://piyopiyocs.blog115.fc2.com/blog-entry-623.html)

[CodeIgniterでも同様の設定を行うことができます](http://manablog.org/codeigniter_gmail/)が、後でそのプログラムをレンタルサーバーなどに移したり、あるいは同じXAMPPで他のPHPプログラムも試されるのであれば、php.iniでまとめて設定しておくと楽かなと思います。